# SetAttribute value for html tag

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I want to set attribute value for below html tag using selenium webdrive. Say for ex... I want to replace 50% to 70% using either JavaScript with Webdriver or Simple webDriver Script.

I try many options but this tag does not have attribute except only class. So Please help me

```
<Span class="abc">50%</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not an attribute value, that's *content*. So you'll want the Selenium optionfor setting *content* rather than attributes.

You mention JavaScript. You can set the content of a `span` in JavaScript by getting a reference to the `span` element and setting its `innerHTML` property (or accessing the `Text` node it contains and setting its `nodeValue` property).

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest way to assign value to `span` is

```
document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML = "70%";
```